# c++ programm exiting unexpectedly

Tags: c++

I have a Programm, where I have two nested for loops. The outer Iteration parameter is x, the inner y. This code continues to x:5 and y:4, however i expect it to keep on going till x: 1000 and y:999.

Can you explain what is going on?
So i have this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    printf("start");
    long double  result;
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < 1000; x++) {
        for (unsigned int y = 0; y < x; y++) {
            result = pow(50, x) - pow(50, y);
            if (((int)result) == result && result!=0) {
                printf("x: %07d y:%07d \r\n", x, y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you worked out what the value of `pow(50, 5)` and `pow(50,4)` actually evaluates to?

Comment: "This code continues to..." what does that mean? Does it crash? If so, what's the error?

Comment: The programmer's secret weapon is the debugger. With the debugger you can run the program on your terms, instruction by instruction if you have to, and see what it is really doing. Set a breakpoint to quickly advance to before where the program fails and then start stepping to gather information about the cause of the failure. I recommend adding `int resultint = (int)result;` so you can more easily inspect `((int)result) == result`. Once you've gathered more information you'll either have your answer or be able to better focus the question.

Comment: @scohe001 I set a breakpoint the line, where result is assigned, and after x:5 and y:4 it just doesn't hit. However, if I continue manually, it does go through the iterations. Maybe to avoid unessesary running of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
        if (((int)result) == result && result!=0) {
            printf("x: %07d y:%07d \r\n", x, y);
```

more precisely in the condition

```
            ((int)result) == result      // the same as (int)result == result
```

which restricts *only your output* to the point where `x == 5` and `y == 4` — looping itself *continues* to `x == 1000` and `y == 999`.

You may see it if you change `int` to `long int` in that condition:

```
        if (((long int)result) == result && result!=0) {
            printf("x: %07d y:%07d \r\n", x, y);
```

Your output will be longer (up to `x == 11` and `y == 10` in my machine).

Comment: While this does work, I have found the lovely modf function. It provides you with the decimal part, and puts the rest in a double pointer. Now my code goes up to x: 181 and y: 180, because at that point the result variable overflows.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: because, as remarked, my proposed answer was strongly incorrect, so please allow me to fix it.**

### Min/Max Values for Data types

I want to start by referring to the [code where you can easily display the maximum values for certain data types](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-cookbook/0596007612/ch03s08.html) on your system:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void showMinMax() {
   cout << "\tmin: " << numeric_limits<T>::min() << endl;
   cout << "\tmax: " << numeric_limits<T>::max() << endl;
   cout << endl;
}
```

and in your `main()` function

```cpp
cout << "int: " << endl;
showMinMax<int>();
cout << "long int: " << endl;
showMinMax<long int>();
cout << "float: " << endl;
showMinMax<float>();
cout << "double: " << endl;
showMinMax<double>();
cout << "long double: " << endl;
showMinMax<long double>();
```

Print these limits once for debugging and keep them in mind.

### Your if-clause

Now, *@MarianD*'s remark is very much correct: You (try) to save the result in a `long double` variable, but then you squeeze it back into an `long int` (or even an `int`) for comparison. This does not get you the effect, you most liked wished for.

Have a look at another debugging print statement in the `if`-clause:

```cpp
if (((long int)result) == result && result!=0) {
    // Compare the value for the long int with the max value for the long int data type
    printf("Comparing:\n\t(int)result: %d\n\t(long int)result: %ld\n\tresult: %Le\n",(int)result,(long int)result,result);
    printf("x: %07d y:%07d \r\n", x, y);
}
```

Here you can observe the values that you compare, upon successful comparison. You will notice, that the last value for `(long int)result` (at `x==11` and `y == 10`) is close to the maximum value of `long int` on your system.

I do not quite understand why you make such a comparison, but you will run into other trouble as you progress in iterations:

### The pow() function

As you can see in the [C++ Reference for the `pow()` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/), depending on the input arguments it returns different output arguments. I added another debugging statement, to break the loop, if the result of the `pow()`  function is `Inf`:

```cpp
long double ld50 = 50.0;
rx = pow(ld50,x);
if(isinf(rx)){
    printf("pow(50,%d) = Inf\n",x); rx = pow(ld50,x-1);
    printf("Last valid value pow(50,%d) = %Le\n",x-1,rx);
    break;
}
```

See also the [C++ Reference for the `isinf()` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/isinf/).
Depending on the C++ Standard that you are using, e.g. C++98

> double pow (double base     , double exponent);
>     float pow (float base      , float exponent);
>     long double pow (long double base, long double exponent);
>     double pow (double base     , int exponent);
>     long double pow (long double base, int exponent);

you have to vary the types of your input argument to get the desired output argument of the `pow()` function.

### Proposed solution

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    printf("start\n");
    long double result, rx, ry;
    long double ld50 = 50.0;
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < 1000; x++) {
        // Computing the power apriori in long doubles
        rx = pow(ld50,x);
        // Checking for infinity, if true, break
        if(isinf(rx)){
            printf("pow(50,%d) = Inf\n",x); rx = pow(ld50,x-1);
            printf("Last valid value pow(50,%d) = %Le\n",x-1,rx);
            break;
        }
        for (unsigned int y = 0; y < x; y++) {
            ry = pow(ld50,y);
            result = rx-ry;
            printf("x: %07d y:%07d res: %Le\r\n", x, y,result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Infinity minus Infinity is still Infinity" [citation needed]

Comment: According to Wikipedia infinity - infinity = NaN: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Comment: Add a few as and a b and you can have infinite bananas and a food source for your very own Shakespeare play generator.

Answer (score 0):

To debug your program I have added the following "printf" before "if" statement

```
        printf("x: %07d y:%07d %d %Lf\r\n", x, y, (int)result, result);
```

And I can see the following result:

```
...
x: 0000005 y:0000004 306250000 306250000.000000 
x: 0000006 y:0000000 -2147483648 15624999999.000000
...
```

You can see the integer type overflow when you convert long double to in and  result != (int)result that is why your program stops printing data after x:4 y:5

But why do you need the "if" statement? What condition are you trying to check? Maybe you can just remove it?

Comment: I am trying to find squares for the expression 50^m-50^n. One I am able to try the solution I will report back.

Comment: It seems you should try to solve algorithmic problem to avoid overflow. I don't know how to solve it, but maybe the following formula can help you a^x±a^y=a^x•(1±a^(y/x))